# The Length of the Longest Maximal Chain Among The Set of All Integer Partitions with Dominance Ordering

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, oeis

**Question:** I write the following infinite table:
$$T= \text{ }\begin{matrix}
1\\
1&1\\
1&2&1\\
1&1&3&1\\
1&1&1&4&1\\
1&2&1&1&5&1\\
1&1&3&1&1&6&1\\
1&1&1&4&1&1&7&1\\
1&1&1&1&5&1&1&8&1\\
1&\color{red}{2}&1&1&1&6&1&1&9&1\\
1&1&3&1&1&1&7&1&1&10&1\\
1&1&1&4&1&1&1&8&1&1&11&1\\
\vdots\\
\end{matrix}$$

I write $t_{ij}$ for the entry in the $i-$th row and $j-$th column of $T.$ **What is a closed formula for the value of $t_{ij}$ in only the indeterminants $i$ and $j $ ?**

---

The $j-$th column of $T$ might be interpreted as $k$ $1'$s followed by $j.$ For example column 2 might be written as $1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,\ldots,$ which can be found in the OEIS as A042974(N). In particular I have without proof:
$$
t_{i2}=\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\bigg(3-\cos\bigg[\pi\sqrt{8i+9}\bigg]\bigg)\bigg\rfloor
$$
For example:
$$
t_{10,2}=\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\bigg(3-\cos\bigg[\pi\sqrt{8*10+9}\bigg]\bigg)\bigg\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\bigg(3-\cos\bigg[\pi\sqrt{89}\bigg]\bigg)\bigg\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(4)\bigg\rfloor=\color{red}{2}
$$
This formula might be leveraged to calculate the more general term $t_{ij}.$

---

The following are conjectural observations:

1. It appears the sum of the entries on the $i-$th row of $T$ equals $A006463(N+1).$ A motivation for this sequence is shown in the reference: R. P. Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, Cambridge, Vol. 2, 1999; Problem 7.2(f). In particular it appears the row sums of $T$ are the length of the longest maximal chain in $Par(N);$ where $Par(N)$ denotes the set of all partitions of $N$ with dominance ordering.
2. It appears the sum of the non-unit entries, those entries not equal to 1, on the $N-$the row of $T$ equals $A023546(N+1).$
3. It appears the sum of unit entries,  those entries equal to 1, on the $N-$th row of $T$ equals $A122797(N+1).$
4. It appears following 1,2 and 3 this equation holds:
   $$A006463(N+1)=A023546(N+1)+A122797(N-1)$$

Note I am not asking for formulas for 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: I do not understand precisely what the pattern in the table is meant to be.  If I were to guess the next several rows of the table, what it to say that those guesses were correct or incorrect?  Patterns which appear to be true for the first several many entries do not necessarily need to remain true for later entries.

Comment: So I'm guessing you don't want a piecewise function like $T(i,j) = j$ if $i-j+2$ is a triangular number, otherwise $T(i,j) = 1$ (assuming $i\ge j$).  The possible connections (1)-(4) are very interesting.

Comment: @BrianHopkins yes no piecewise functions.  I now conjecture that connections (1)-(4) are in fact rue.