# Dominance Order on the Set of Partitions and The Hamming Weight of A Binary String

Tags: binary, integer-partitions

> **Question**: A partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_s)$ is a tuple of positive integers listed in non decreasing order such that $\sum_{i=1}\lambda_{i}=N.$ Each $\lambda_{i}$ is called a part of the partition. I write $\mathcal{P}(N)$ for the set of all partitions of $N.$ I write $\leq$ for the [dominance order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_order) on $\mathcal{P}(n).$ Indeed $\leq$ induces a partial order on $\mathcal{P}(N).$ Brylawski has shown that $(\mathcal{P}(N),\leq)$ is a lattice; which for shorthand is normally denoted by $L(N).$ Brylawski gives the following formulas for $N>1$ of the maximum number of elements covered by any element of $L(N):$
> $$
> \max_{L(N)}N=\bigg\lfloor-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{8N+9}\bigg\rfloor \label{a}\tag{1}
> $$
> Consider the binary string $$B=010010001000010000010000001\ldots$$ I write $B(N)$ for the first $N$ bits of $B.$ I write $\chi_{w}(B(N))$ to count occurrences of the string $w$ up to and including the first $N$ bits of $B.$ Now, suppose $w=1$ then calculating $\chi_{1}(B(N))$ is the same as determining the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#:%7E:text=The%20Hamming%20weight%20of%20a,string%20of%20the%20same%20length) of $B(N).$ Curiously
> $$
> \chi_{1}(B(N))=\bigg\lfloor-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{8N+9}\bigg\rfloor \label{b}\tag{2}
> $$
> What if any are the intuitions that might relate partitions under dominance ordering to hamming weights in our binary string $B?$

---

By Taking $w=01$ the formula for $\chi_{10}(B(N))$ is the exact formula given by Brylawski for $N\geq1.$ The paper by Brylawski can be found on Science Direct: [The lattice of integer partitions Corollary 2.10 -Thomas Brylawski](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73900940). Also worth mentioning are the partial sums of $1$ and $2$ which are related to the sequence
[A023535](https://oeis.org/A023535).

Comment: Not sure it will help, but may I suggest you have a look at our work on Brylawski's lattice entitled "The lattice of integer partitions and its infinite extension"? It is available on arxiv.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0008020.pdf). I also have another [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864350/the-length-of-the-longest-maximal-chain-among-the-set-of-all-integer-partitions) that you might be interested in seeing.

Comment: Nice problem, thanks! and to be honest I already up-voted it a few days ago ;) But I fear I will not be of more help.